How to repair chipped window paint?
My cat scratched up my window sill paint. I want to make sure that the next coat(s) of paint I put on are durable and will not get easily chipped. There’s no water or rot on the wood. Edit - Also, I rent so I'm just looking to fix this and not do anything drastic.
Could you provide the best way to presumably sand, paint, and fix this?

So.... how do you feel about aluminium windows?... But that would only divert the scratching to the next best thing. Gentle training of your cat's behaviour towards a dedicated cat scratching post might be more likely to produce a long-lasting finish on your window surrounds. I am not a cat psychologist.

I rent. I'm just looking to repair the window sill.

That would be a good thing to [edit] into your question so that answers can be more relevant ;) Also, you'll still need to show your cat how to adjust their scratching behaviour anyway.

Cat might have helped, but it looks more like paint peeling than scratched.  Usually caused by bad/not good surface prep before painting.  Remove all loose paint, sand smooth, clean, and paint again.

@crip659 I'd agree. Anything I should do to prevent this going forward?

@AndrewMorton I thought this was Home Improvement. Not a cat psychologist thread?

Paint will bond to the first thing it touches.  It should be a clean surface without dust/dirt/oil(or similar)/moisture/loose old paint. So sand/scrape loose paint, vacuum/wipe down(TSP is useful), make sure the wood/surface is dry and smooth, before painting.  Make sure no moisture leaks from the window.

Did the cat scratch the window frame too?

No matter what paint you use and how diligent you apply it, your cat can ruin it. You can sand prime and repaint, but the cat will just scratch it up again.
Cats claws are like knives, ( you probably know) They can carve through any paint.  You should look into making the windowsill an unpleasant place for your cat to be.  Some well placed cactus plants and some pepper sprinkled around may do it. I have seen a video where people covered their counters with aluminium foil to keep the cat off.  It worked. The cat hated it.  Unfortunately your cat may just decide to damage another place in the house.

As @crip659 said she n the comments: remove loose paint, apply appropriate primer, apply paint. Depending on what the frame is currently painted with, it may be easier to get consistent appearance by repainting the entire trim rather than just trying to patch that one spot... but for a rental you may not want to make that much effort
Glossy paints, especially oil-based enamel paints, may have a tougher surface than matte paints if you expect the cat to continue doing this.
Personally I'd be really tempted to not bother trying to fix it until I was moving out and was concerned about my security deposit.
And I'd focus on giving the cat better scratching surfaces, but that belongs in the pets stack

You've been given repainting advice in other answers.  To actually prevent a recurrence, get a piece of tempered glass, or acrylic sheet (if you're OK periodically replacing it) cut to fit the window sill.

@RMDman is right, you cant do anything other than repair the damage.
Using a different cleaning solution does help. Cats hate vinegar, love bleach, and other chemically products.
A homeopathic solution on your window sills will keep your cat from scratching it to death. Like 1 part vinegar 100 parts water. Capful in a spray bottle.
